# copy link list in java

Tags: java, data-structures

```
public Linearlist mul(Linearlist l1, Linearlist l2) {
    Linearlist sum = new Linearlist();
    int carry = 0;
    long pow = 0;
    while (l2.size > 0) {
        Linearlist row = new Linearlist();
        Linearlist temp1 = l1;
        int operand = l2.Delfirst();

        for (int i = 0; i < pow; i++) {
            row.InsertFirst(0);
        }

        pow++;
        while (temp1.size > 0) {
            int result;
            result = temp1.Delfirst() * operand + carry;
            if (result > 9) {
                carry = result / 10;
                result = result % 10;
            }
            row.InsertFirst(result);
        }
        if (carry > 0) {
            row.InsertFirst(carry);
        }

        sum = sumList(row, sum);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

hi this my code and i want to multiply numbers of two list 
so write this code and it works for first delete on my second list .
when i debug this code in first time second while work 
and next time it doesn't go to second while
where is the problem that `temp1.size` is not bigger than 0 ???

Answer (score 0):

because when you assign two link list together they get same address
so the assigned link list actually is a first link list .
for assign a link list you must make copy of first link list to second one